# Youtube API 401 Error

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube API to try some things out and I can't get to do anything without getting the error. Expected response code is `200`, got `401: User authentication required`.

I have authenticated my Youtube channel though

```
session_start();

$clientLibraryPath = 'Youtube/library';
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientLibraryPath);


require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');

function getAuthSubRequestUrl()
{
$next = 'LINK';
$scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com';
$secure = false;
$session = true;
return Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubTokenUri($next, $scope, $secure, $session);
}

function getAuthSubHttpClient()
{
if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && !isset($_GET['token']) ){
    echo '<a href="' . getAuthSubRequestUrl() . '">Login!</a>';
    return;
} else if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
  $_SESSION['sessionToken'] =   Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token']);

}

$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient($_SESSION['sessionToken']);
return $httpClient;
}
getAuthSubHttpClient();

$cID = "Client ID";
$aID = "App ID";
$dK = "DEV KEY"; // Hidden
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $aID, $cID, $dK);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here to login into my account?

Comment: Is the user going through the full flow (browser based redirect, etc)? Also, is there a reason you are using AuthSub instead of OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your code hosted in the exact same URL as you set in the `Google Code Console`

If your `javascript origins` is set to `http://example.com`, make sure your code isn't being hosted at `http://example.com/something` or `http://something.example.com`! This seemed to work for me :)